# need to pick one ip from the nslookup output

Tags: shell-script

Trying to create script where i can select one of the ip from nslookup IP and assign to a variable.

need guidance. Thanks in advance.

```
 nslookup yahoo.com | grep Address
Address:        192.168.1.1#53
Address: 98.137.11.163
Address: 74.6.231.20
Address: 98.137.11.164
Address: 74.6.231.21
Address: 74.6.143.26
Address: 74.6.143.25
Address: 2001:4998:24:120d::1:1
Address: 2001:4998:44:3507::8000
Address: 2001:4998:124:1507::f001
Address: 2001:4998:24:120d::1:0
Address: 2001:4998:124:1507::f000
Address: 2001:4998:44:3507::8001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `dig` is easier to use in scripts. To get the address you can use `dig +short yahoo.com`. To get single line use this `dig +short yahoo.com | head -n 1`.

Comment: +1.  Can also use `shuf` instead of `head` if you want a random IP.  e.g. `dig +short yahoo.com | shuf -n 1`

Comment: Thanks Zasda, it worked.  

$ dig +short yahoo.com | head -n 1
98.137.11.164

is there a way to use this ip in next command which is : whois

Comment: never mind got the answer....below code helped.

while read ip
do
     whois -r $ip
done<file.txt

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, but works:

- Pipe `nslookup`'s output to `grep` with the `-A1` parameter (returns the line matched plus one);
- Pipe this output to `tail -n1` to get only the last line;
- "`sed`" your way to drop the "Address:" part and get only the IP.

Example:

```
$ nslookup google.com | grep -A1 Name | tail -n1
Address: 2800:3f0:4004:805::200e
```

If you want only an IPv4, make sure to include the `-query=A` parameter to `nslookup`:

```
$ nslookup -query=A google.com | grep -A1 Name | tail -n1 | sed 's/Address: //'
216.58.222.110
```

Comment: `grep -A1 Name | tail -n1` isn't needed, sed is enough.   e.g. `nslookup google.com | sed -n 's/^Address: //p'`

Comment: BTW, in case you're wondering why that doesn't match the server's address and port (127.0.0.1#53) in the first paragraph, it's because `nslookup` outputs a TAB character after the colon for the first paragraph (server info), and a SPACE character after the colon for the second paragraph (answers section).   I guess they were trying to make it easier to extract answers.

Comment: Thanks Tango this worked.